# How to remove paypal express checkout link from mini cart in right column

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, payment, payment-gateway, paypal-express

I have just set myself up with PayPal payments pro and got it installed and tested etc. But there's one thing i don't like which is the PayPal express checkout link appearing in my mini cart in the right column of my website.

How do i remove this link?

I still want the link to be there on checkout so turning it off in the config menu isn't an option because it turns off both links.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy enough. All you need to do is remove the block that is inserted via the paypal.xml You can do this via your custom theme local.xml file located in your layout folder.

Thus if you look at `/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/paypal.xml` you will find the directive that places that link in this block:

```
<default>
        <reference name="topCart.extra_actions">
            <block type="paypal/express_shortcut" name="paypal.partner.top_cart.shortcut" template="paypal/express/shortcut.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions">
            <block type="paypal/express_shortcut" name="paypal.partner.cart_sidebar.shortcut" template="paypal/express/shortcut.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
```

Thus to remove, in your local.xml theme file you can place:

```
<default>
    <!-- remove from top cart -->
    <reference name="topCart.extra_actions">
        <remove name="paypal.partner.top_cart.shortcut"/>
    </reference>
    <!-- remove from sidebar -->
    <reference name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions">
        <remove name="paypal.partner.cart_sidebar.shortcut"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can disable all PayPal images through the configuration.

System > Config > Payment Methods > PayPal > PayPal Express Checkout > Basic Settings > Frontend Experience Settings > PayPal Product Logo

Comment: Hi, I did not actually know this (don't really use paypal), however as per OP's request : "I still want the link to be there on checkout so turning it off in the config menu isn't an option because it turns off both links." this is not the correct solution for him.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1.9.1: Add this in local.xml

```
<default>
    <reference name="right">
        <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Answer (score -1):

One can also remove it via **"Layout Update XML"** - no file changes are needed

[image: Valid XHTML].