# Magento 2: How to remove Paypal Logo from MiniCart & Shopping Cart Page?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, paypal-express, mini-cart

I'm using Magento 2 CE with Porto Theme.

Also referred but it's for Magento 1

[How to remove paypal express checkout link from mini cart in right column](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11550/how-to-remove-paypal-express-checkout-link-from-mini-cart-in-right-column)

I have tried from Admin Paypal Settings. But logo is still displaying on

**How to remove it from Mini Cart & Shopping Cart Page?**

Answer (score 5):

You can remove logo using backend.

```
Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Method
```

**Paypal Express Checkout Tab**

Click **`Configure`** Button,

```
Go To Basic Settings - Paypal Express Checkout section,
Click on Advanced settings.
```

**Set No to Display On shopping Cart option.**

Comment: I already tried on Magento 2 CE. It's not working at all.

Comment: Have you remove cache and var folder? Are you using Paypal Express Checkout?

Comment: Yes tried all. I think need to override with xml file. Last option

Comment: have you found any solutions for this issue, If yes Please share your solutions.

Comment: Nope. I didn't get my solutions. Answer which u have given i already tried before Posting the Question

Comment: This bug is still not fixed as of 2.1.6, see Erfan's answer for a follow-up.

Comment: Just to add a note here in case anyone else has the same problem I did with the mini cart.  The mini cart caches pretty heavily and adding a product to your cart flushes it, when cache:clean does not.

Answer (score 5):

Copy this file to your custom theme:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/minicart/content.html
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/Magento_Checkout/web/template/minicart/content.html
```

And remove the line number **59**:

```
<div data-bind="html: getCartParam('extra_actions')"></div>
```

---

Or copy the file that renders the specific PayPal logo here:

```
vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/templates/express/shortcut.phtml
```

Answer (score 4):

There's a bug in Magento 2.1 where "Display On shopping Cart" option doesn't work.

More information: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6073

Answer (score 2):

- Login in admin panel
- Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Method
- Select Payments Standard tab -> Basic Settings - PayPal Website Payments Standard
- Advanced Settings -> Display on Shopping Cart => **No**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create `event.xml` in your custom module like this and disable "paypal_shortcuts" observer

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="shortcut_buttons_container">
        <observer name="paypal_shortcuts" instance="Magento\Paypal\Observer\AddPaypalShortcutsObserver" disabled="true"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Erfan for finding the Magento bug link.

Magento has indeed fixed this issue but it has only been applied to their 2.2 code base. If you are on a previous version you can replicate their commit changes,  https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/b4b721444be8c6257d64059b3b0b5d0f1fb1466b into your site.

In a custom module overwrite the PayPal Minicart Button Block

**app/code/YourCompany/YourModule/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Paypal\Block\Express\InContext\Minicart\Button" type="YourCompany\YourModule\Block\Express\InContext\Minicart\Button" />
</config>
```

**app/code/YourCompany/YourModule/Block/Express/InContext/Minicart/Button.php**

```
<?php
namespace EsteSolutions\AddToCart\Block\Express\InContext\Minicart;

class Button extends \Magento\Paypal\Block\Express\InContext\Minicart\Button
{
 /**
 * Check `visible_on_cart` config value
 *
 * @return bool
 */
private function isVisibleOnCart()
{
    return (bool)(int) $this->config->getValue('visible_on_cart');
}   

/**
 * @return bool
 */
protected function shouldRender()
{
    return $this->payment->isAvailable($this->session->getQuote())
        && $this->isMiniCart
        && $this->isInContext()
        && $this->isVisibleOnCart();
}
}
?>
```

Comment: $this->config and $this->payment are private variables...